# Previous version of the source code(Talend) from nexus repo

Tags: talend, nexus3, tac

I have a incorrect version of the job where I published to TAC is there a way to get the previous version from the nexus repo

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you didn't overwrite the artifact it will still be in nexus however if you didn't re-version the code and haven't got backups etc. on your nexus server it's unlikely.

Also you should add more detail on stack overflow posts or they will keep getting downvoted by the community you should include a detailed question including some of the steps you went though to try to resolve you issue.

Lastly if you have TAC your using the enterprise version of Talend which usually means your eligible support from Talend themselves I'll PM you support email address.